# Controlling PowerPoint from Golang

Tags: powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to control (mainly previous slide/next slide) a PowerPoint app running on a windows computer from a Golang binary running on the same computer.
One way could be to send keystrokes (I've not tried it yet), but I'm looking for something more "API friendly".
Can it be done?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Golang, but assuming it can do COM automation, if you can get a reference to the PowerPoint application object, it has two methods that will allow you to move forward and backward in a slide show. This is what they'd look like if doing COM automation from VB etc:

```
.SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
.SlideShowWindows(1).View.Previous
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have zero experience with COM but I'll search about it.